# 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found when trying to install 'Illuminate\Html' in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container

I understand that there are several similar questions here but none of them fixed my problem.

I'm trying to add the HtmlServiceProvider with Laravel 5 on Ubuntu 14.04. I keep getting the following error:

```
dl@dl-VirtualBox:~/l5todo$ composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /home/dl/l5todo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found    



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                       
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found i  
  n /home/dl/l5todo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository  
  .php on line 146
```

My vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository
      .php looks like:

```
   /**
 * Create a new provider instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $provider
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
 */
public function createProvider($provider)
{
    return new $provider($this->app);//line 146
}
```

My /.../config/app.php looks like:

```
'providers' => [

    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, //newly added

   ......
],
'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    ......
  'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,


],
```

In my compose.Jason

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",

    "Illuminate/Html": "~5.0"
},
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Sorry again if this question seems duplicated to you.

---

**`composer update` works if I remove provider and aliases I added. But after I add them back in, same error appears.**

Comment: I'm sorry for asking really stupid questions but they do have to be asked... 1) did you do `composer install` (or `composer update`)? 2) did you do `composer dump-autoload` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, `composer dump-autoload` works fine but `composer install` and `composer update` I got the class not found exception.

Comment: is composer.json case sensitive? In other words, does `"illuminate/html"` make a difference?

Comment: Also, you should run a composer install/update *before* adding the service provider in app.php.

Comment: I think it might be case sensitive so I kept them consistent. I did the update after modified app.php. should I remove provider then update?

Comment: Yes, remove the service provider along with the Facades. After composer update, add them back in.

Comment: `composer update` works if I remove provider and aliases I added. But after I add them back in, same error appears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89623/discussion-between-daolincheng-and-chris-burton).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1**

In composer.json under require, add:

`"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",`

**Step 2**

run `composer update` in your terminal

**Step 3**

Add the following in config/app.php under providers:

`Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`

**Step 4**

Add the following in config/app.php under aliases:

`'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,`

Comment: The order is very important. I edited both files first, ended up getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
composer.json

```
"illuminate/html": "~5.0"
```

**Step 2**
process dump-autoload

```
composer.phar dump-autoload
```

**Step 3** app.php

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'Form'  => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
```

**Step 4** flush caching (if needed)

```
composer.phar dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```